# How to output wav file to microphone input using NAudio in C#

Tags: c#, naudio

I found NAudio Library during making simple audio editor program.
I want to output wav(*.wav) file to microphone input stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something natively supported by Windows Audio APIs, and so NAudio isn't able to help you with this. You need an audio 'loopback' device driver [like this](http://virtual-audio-cable.en.softonic.com/), or physically connect an output of your soundcard to an input with an audio cable.